# C# joining multiple tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 4 tables, Quote, QuoteMeasure, QuoteMeasureProduct and Product.

I need to list all the products associated with each quote.

I also need to show all measures associated with each quote, I am unsure as to how complex this query needs to be.

I have tried the following:

```
var products = new List<Product>(); 

            var query = work.Quotes.Join(products,       
              (q => q.Id),   
              (p => p.QuoteMeasureProducts.Any(qm => qm.QuoteMeasureId.ToString() == quoteId )), 
              ((q, p) => new { Quote = q, Product = p }));
```

This code is sitting in a ViewModel so I also need to make the information available to my HTML view.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using associations?

Comment: I couldn't find any associations with the product table.

Comment: "find"? Aren't you writing this program yourself?

Comment: Not entirely, the db was written before I joined

Comment: Database, not the Object Relational Mapping.